# In Python, how can I detect whether the computer is on battery power?

Tags: python, windows, pygame

I'm playing around with pygame, and one thing I'd like to do is reduce the number of frames per second when the computer is on battery power (to lower the CPU usage and extend battery life).

How can I detect, from Python, whether the computer is currently on battery power?

I'm using Python 3.1 on Windows.

Comment: Or you could use a bool, that F1 toggles. When on call with 30, else 0. http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#Clock.tick

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to do it without `win32api`, you can use the built-in [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) module. I usually run CPython without `win32api`, so I kinda like these solutions.

It's a tiny bit more work for `GetSystemPowerStatus()` because you have to define the `SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS` structure, but not bad.

```
# Get power status of the system using ctypes to call GetSystemPowerStatus

import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

class SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('ACLineStatus', wintypes.BYTE),
        ('BatteryFlag', wintypes.BYTE),
        ('BatteryLifePercent', wintypes.BYTE),
        ('Reserved1', wintypes.BYTE),
        ('BatteryLifeTime', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('BatteryFullLifeTime', wintypes.DWORD),
    ]

SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_P = ctypes.POINTER(SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS)

GetSystemPowerStatus = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetSystemPowerStatus
GetSystemPowerStatus.argtypes = [SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_P]
GetSystemPowerStatus.restype = wintypes.BOOL

status = SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS()
if not GetSystemPowerStatus(ctypes.pointer(status)):
    raise ctypes.WinError()
print('ACLineStatus', status.ACLineStatus)
print('BatteryFlag', status.BatteryFlag)
print('BatteryLifePercent', status.BatteryLifePercent)
print('BatteryLifeTime', status.BatteryLifeTime)
print('BatteryFullLifeTime', status.BatteryFullLifeTime)
```

On my system that prints this (basically meaning "desktop, plugged in"):

```
ACLineStatus 1
BatteryFlag -128
BatteryLifePercent -1
BatteryLifeTime 4294967295
BatteryFullLifeTime 4294967295
```

Comment: There is a bug in wintypes (http://bugs.python.org/issue16376) when BYTE is defined as c_byte, not c_ubyte. Therefore values in SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS won't match those defined in documentation. Use c_ubyte instead of BYTE.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `Reserved1` is now `SystemStatusFlag` as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-system_power_status#:~:text=Note%C2%A0%C2%A0This%20flag%20and%20the%20GUID_POWER_SAVING_STATUS%20GUID%20were%20introduced%20in%20Windows%C2%A010.%20This%20flag%20was%20previously%20reserved%2C%20named%20Reserved1%2C%20and%20had%20a%20value%20of%200.)

Comment: It was finally fixed: [\[GitHub\]: python/cpython - gh-60580: Fix a wrong type of ctypes.wintypes.BYTE](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/97579).

Answer (score 11):

The most reliable way to retrieve this information in C is by using [GetSystemPowerStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372693(v=vs.85).aspx). If no battery is present `ACLineStatus` will be set to `128`. [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) exposes this information under Linux, Windows and FreeBSD, so to check if battery is present you can do this

```
>>> import psutil
>>> has_battery = psutil.sensors_battery() is not None
```

If a battery is present and you want to know whether the power cable is plugged in you can do this:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.sensors_battery()
sbattery(percent=99, secsleft=20308, power_plugged=True)
>>> psutil.sensors_battery().power_plugged
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

<strike>It is easy, all you have to do is to call Windows API function [GetSystemPowerStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Python, probably by importing `win32api` module.</strike>

**EDIT:** `GetSystemPowerStatus()` is not yet implemented in `win32api` as of build 219 (2014-05-04).

Comment: @swati if you install ActiveState Python you will not need to install pywin32 anymore, it is included.

Comment: Alas ActiveState python is some kind of proprietary software, and not opensource á la vanilla Python.

Comment: It is a commercial product, still open source and you do not have to pay (free). Usually I would prefer to use Python.org version but due to the missing modules, that are not so easy to compile on Windows due to the big number of compilers it makes a lot of sense to use ActivePython. I recommend this from my experience.

Comment: Generally, ActiveState distributions are just batteries included distos of the language in question, and you don't need to pay for them. They have software you can pay for (Komodo), but I believe all the language packages they offer are free to download.

Comment: @Sorin, it'd be nice if you could provide a working example of the win32api version.

Comment: Kindly check [\[SO\]: In Python, how can I detect whether the computer is on battery power? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75347540/4788546) :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple method for cross platform power status indication is the 'power' module which you can install with pip

```
    import power
    ans = power.PowerManagement().get_providing_power_source_type()
    if not ans:
        print "plugged into wall socket"
    else:
        print "on battery"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working anymore on MacOS as of March 2020. Maybe since Catalina?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `acpi`.From wikipedia

> In a computer, the Advanced Configuration and Power Interface provides an open standard that operating systems can use to discover and configure computer hardware components, to perform power management by putting unused components to sleep, and to perform status monitoring.

Then use the `subprocess` module in python

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'acpi -b'

# for python 3.7+
p = subprocess.run(cmd.split(), shell=True, capture_output=True)
battery_info, error = p.stdout.decode(), p.stderr.decode()

# for python3.x (x<6)
battery_info = subprocess.check_output(cmd.split(), shell=True).decode('utf-8')

print (battery_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

[[SO]: In Python, how can I detect whether the computer is on battery power? (@BenHoyt's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6156606/4788546) is portable and doesn't require extra packages, but it's negatively impacted (until *Python **v3.12***) by a *CTypes* (*WinTypes*) bug.
More details about the bug (and fix, workaround): [[SO]: Why ctypes.wintypes.BYTE is signed, but native windows BYTE is unsigned? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75345283/4788546).

Anyway, I submitted **[[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Add GetSystemPowerStatus wrapper](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/pull/2010)** for *GetSystemPowerStatus* function to be available in *Win32API*.

Building *win32api.pyd* locally and overwriting the one from *site-packages* directory (as I mentioned in the *Test* section), yields:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q006153860]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Power cable unplugged
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test1_pw32\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import win32api as wapi;from pprint import pprint as pp;pp(wapi.GetSystemPowerStatus(), sort_dicts=0);print(\"\nDone.\n\")"
> {'ACLineStatus': 0,
>  'BatteryFlag': 1,
>  'BatteryLifePercent': 99,
>  'SystemStatusFlag': 0,
>  'BatteryLifeTime': 13094,
>  'BatteryFullLifeTime': 4294967295}
>
> Done.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Plug in power cable
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test1_pw32\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import win32api as wapi;from pprint import pprint as pp;pp(wapi.GetSystemPowerStatus(), sort_dicts=0);print(\"\nDone.\n\")"
> {'ACLineStatus': 1,
>  'BatteryFlag': 1,
>  'BatteryLifePercent': 100,
>  'SystemStatusFlag': 0,
>  'BatteryLifeTime': 4294967295,
>  'BatteryFullLifeTime': 4294967295}
>
> Done.
> ```

Check [[SO]: How to change username of job in print queue using python & win32print (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71684828/4788546) (at the end) for possible ways to benefit from the (above) patch.

Worth mentioning (if [[SO]: In Python, how can I detect whether the computer is on battery power? (@GiampaoloRodolà's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988627/4788546) is not clear enough about it) that [[PyPI]: psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil) also uses *GetSystemPowerStatus* in order to retrieve battery information.