# Getting Battery Capacity in Windows with Python

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, pywin32, battery

I am looking to figure out both the current Battery Capacity and the Design Capacity.

So far what I could get to work is using the [Win32_Battery() class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which doesn't give all the information I need (at least not on my system). I used the pure-python [wmi library](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html) for that.

On the other hand I found this which works [In Python, how can I detect whether the computer is on battery power?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153860/in-python-how-can-i-detect-whether-the-computer-is-on-battery-power), but unfortunately it doesn't provide any information on Capacity neither.

The [Battery Information structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [Battery Status structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seem perfect for this. Now I know that I have to use the [DeviceIoControl function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do so and I found this [C++ code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that explains it a little.

I would prefer something that simply uses ctypes and not the python win32api provided by [pywin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32).
If you have an idea how to do this in python please let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you don't want to use `win32api` because you want to use the code across other platforms, so I'm not sure about alternative ways to do this because all systems have different APIs. If u don't need other platforms i may be able to help u

Comment: I have the code working for linux and mac os. I am trying to get something for windows now, the pywin32, win32api would be fine. I was originally just trying to avoid having an external library requirement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tim Golden's excellent [wmi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/) module will, I believe, give you everything you want. You'll just have to do several queries to get everything:

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()
t = wmi.WMI(moniker = "//./root/wmi")

batts1 = c.CIM_Battery(Caption = 'Portable Battery')
for i, b in enumerate(batts1):
    print 'Battery %d Design Capacity: %d mWh' % (i, b.DesignCapacity or 0)


batts = t.ExecQuery('Select * from BatteryFullChargedCapacity')
for i, b in enumerate(batts):
    print ('Battery %d Fully Charged Capacity: %d mWh' % 
          (i, b.FullChargedCapacity))

batts = t.ExecQuery('Select * from BatteryStatus where Voltage > 0')
for i, b in enumerate(batts):
    print '\nBattery %d ***************' % i
    print 'Tag:               ' + str(b.Tag)
    print 'Name:              ' + b.InstanceName

    print 'PowerOnline:       ' + str(b.PowerOnline)
    print 'Discharging:       ' + str(b.Discharging)
    print 'Charging:          ' + str(b.Charging)
    print 'Voltage:           ' + str(b.Voltage)
    print 'DischargeRate:     ' + str(b.DischargeRate)
    print 'ChargeRate:        ' + str(b.ChargeRate)
    print 'RemainingCapacity: ' + str(b.RemainingCapacity)
    print 'Active:            ' + str(b.Active)
    print 'Critical:          ' + str(b.Critical)
```

This is certainly not cross-platform, and it requires a 3rd party resource, but it does work very well.

Comment: I tried this already and two problems came up. First the [CIM_Battery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class does not give you the current Capacity as far as I know. It also generally just doesn't seem to give me most of the data (Meaning I get 0's or other default values). The last part looks interesting though, I am going to try it out and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot pretty much solved all my problems. I have one issue left, the DesignCapacity always returns 0 for me. I tried performing queries and everything but even those just give me errors. I am testing this on bootcamp with windows 8 so that might be the problem there but whatever I can live without the DesignCapacity for now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 13):

The most reliable way to retrieve this information is by using [GetSystemPowerStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372693(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of WMI. [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) exposes this information under Linux, Windows and FreeBSD:

```
>>> import psutil
>>>
>>> def secs2hours(secs):
...     mm, ss = divmod(secs, 60)
...     hh, mm = divmod(mm, 60)
...     return "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hh, mm, ss)
...
>>> battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
>>> battery
sbattery(percent=93, secsleft=16628, power_plugged=False)
>>> print("charge = %s%%, time left = %s" % (battery.percent, secs2hours(battery.secsleft)))
charge = 93%, time left = 4:37:08
```

The relevant commit is [here](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/pull/963/files).

Comment: Lots of problems in it _(Maybe for me only)_.

Comment: psutil.sensors_battery() return None if powered from battery on HP machine https://superuser.com/questions/1394191/getting-battery-capacity-on-hp-pavilion-psutil-returns-none-on-battery-power

Comment: @Valentyn not for me (HP Spectre x360 Convertible)

Answer (score 0):

```
import psutil

battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
plugged = battery.power_plugged
percent = str(battery.percent)
```

The variable percent will have the battery percent.
I have written a small piece of code using python to notify when the battery is fully charged

https://github.com/Mitzzzzz/Battery-Full-Indicator

Kindly check!!

Comment: Why 'secsleft=4294967295' ??? It's 19884 hours. I have only 30% on battery

Comment: @AlexZab that most likely means that it is **not** able to retrieve the secsleft... since this number 4294967295 seems to be the max limit of an unsigned 32-bit integer, indicating a failure

Answer (score 0):

```
**Checking the battery percentage in python can be done using the psutil module as 
follows **

# Installing the psutil module
from  pip._internal import  main
main(["install", "psutil"])
import psutil

battery = psutil.sensors_battery();

# checking if the charger is plugged
if battery.power_plugged:
    print("Charging: ", battery.percent)
else:
    print("Not Charging", battery.percent ,"%");
    print( "Discharge time ", int(battery.secsleft)," sec_lft")
```

Comment: \ Why 'secsleft=4294967295' ??? It's 19884 hours. I have only 30% on battery

Comment: Im not sure, it have been long let me go and check the documentation, then i will come back to you **but i think those units aren't actually second**

Comment: Go ahead and check this script it may help you to get the actual time left. If it doesn't help you hit me up i will fix it for you.    https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/scripts/battery.py

Answer (score 0):

The Most Easiest Form to Know the Battery With Python is using Psutil Module...

```
import psutil    #pip install psutil
battery_detecting = psutil.sensors_battery()
plugged = battery_detecting.power_plugged
percent_battery = str(battery_detecting.percent)
plugged = "Plugged In" if plugged else "Not Plugged In"
print(percent_battery+'% | '+plugged)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
import psutil
import time
battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
while True:
    print("Battery percentage : ", battery.percent)
    print("Power plugged in : ", battery.power_plugged)
    if battery.percent < 35 and battery.power_plugged == False:
        print("Your battry is low")
    time.sleep(5)
```

But this code will run continously until it get's interrupted

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Full Charge Capacity of a battery try this:
I AM USING POWERSHELL NONINTERACTIVE SHELL TO USE THIS COMMAND. THIS IS ONE OF THE EASIEST WAYS TO KNOW BATTERY INFO.

```
systeminfo = subprocess.run(["Powershell", "-NonInteractive", "-Command", "Get-WmiObject", "-Namespace",  "'root\wmi'", "-Query",  "'select FullChargedCapacity  from BatteryFullChargedCapacity'"], capture_output=True).stdout.decode().strip()
print(systeminfo[292:-21])
```

**NOTE:** **THIS ONLY WORKS ON WINDOWS**