# How to use system variables in python?

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-7-x64

How can I access my computer's system variables like battery levels, or battery-life estimates from python? - I'm not sure "system varaiable" is the exact term). I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You want to access environment variables, Then use `Python os package`. or else,
you want to Access Battery Status using python in windows.
[Python Bettery status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380394/getting-battery-capacity-windows-with-python)

Comment: this do not address OP question (first part being about environment, not battery status, second is for ubuntu, not win)

Comment: Sorry @alko you are correct. I have edited my answer.