# How to get battery percentage with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, battery

How to get battery percentage with python?
Maybe some **`win32api`** functions may help.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this:

```
import psutil
battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
plugged = battery.power_plugged
percent = str(battery.percent)
plugged = "Plugged In" if plugged else "Not Plugged In"
print(percent+'% | '+plugged)
```

Library link is [here](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil). And check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380394/getting-battery-capacity-windows-with-python)

Comment: Why are you parsing the string when the object has those attributes ? You just need `battery.percent` and `battery.power_plugged`.

Comment: Good point. I will change it soon

Comment: `psutil.sensors_battery()` returns null sometimes? is there an alternative?