# How can I get my laptop's charging value with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use a Lenovo Thinkpad and need a python program that can get me my laptop's charging percentage.

For Example: 74%, 98%, 16%

I've searched around but can't seem to find exactly what I need

Can anyone help?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380394/getting-battery-capacity-windows-with-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Battery Capacity Windows with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380394/getting-battery-capacity-windows-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import  psutil

print ("battery charge left: " + str(psutil.sensors_battery()[0]) + "%")
```

output

```
battery charge left: 95%
```

Comment: any way to know how many minutes of charging left?

Comment: just change the the zero value into 1 you will get the time left in seconds

Comment: @Ultra ask that in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get remaining time as follows:

```
import psutil as ps
batterystats = dict(ps.sensors_battery()._asdict())
print(batterystats)
timeleft = batterystats.get('secsleft')
percent = batterystats.get('percent')

print('battery percent : '+str(percent)+'%')
print('time left (secs) : '+str(timeleft)+' secs')
```

The answer is in seconds you can convert it though.

Comment: tell me if you need to know if the battery is charging

Comment: it says that batterystats has no function "get"

Comment: hmm , it works in python 2.7

Comment: not sure for 3.x

Comment: oh ok cz I'm using python 3x

Comment: it will and should work now

Comment: check it out and tell me

Comment: did it work if yes please ⬆ vote

Comment: Works in Python 3.8.5

Comment: yeah i fixed it !