# Accessing the battery signals for laptop

Tags: python, data-transfer

I would like to log the battery signals of my laptop such as voltage, current, and temperature. I mean I want to create a GUI (using Python) to monitor these signals and log them.

I'm wondering if it is any solution to access this signals?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Battery Capacity in Windows with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380394/getting-battery-capacity-in-windows-with-python)

Comment: This link should get you started.  As far as creating a GUI, that's another ballgame. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-script-to-show-laptop-battery-percentage/

Answer (score 0):

Use psutil:

```
import psutil
psutil.sensors_battery()
# Output: sbattery(percent=100, secsleft=<BatteryTime.POWER_TIME_UNLIMITED: -2>, power_plugged=True)
```