# Why ctypes.wintypes.BYTE is signed, but native windows BYTE is unsigned?

Tags: python, c, windows, python-2.7, ctypes

Python 2.7 on Windows:

```
from ctypes import wintypes
print wintypes.BYTE  # ctypes.c_byte
```

MSDN

A **BYTE** - 8 bit.

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE
```

Comment: It's that way because Thomas Heller defined it as `c_byte` back in 2003, when the file was named [windows.py](http://ctypes.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ctypes/ctypes/win32/windows.py?hideattic=0&revision=1.1&view=markup), circa ctypes 0.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

As @ErykSun mentioned in his comment, it's an old bug which somehow got away.
It was however spotted (here are a couple of *URL*s - surely there are more):

- [[GitHub]: python/cpython - wrong type for wintypes.BYTE](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/60580) (since late 2012)
- [[SO]: In Python, how can I detect whether the computer is on battery power? (@BenHoyt's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6156606/4788546)

But it was fixed by [[GitHub]: python/cpython - gh-60580: Fix a wrong type of ctypes.wintypes.BYTE](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/97579) (on *20230126* - I was just about to submit a *PR* myself, if I didn't find this one).

So, the **first version that will have it right, is *Python 3.12***.

Usually (when it really matters) I do:

```py
from ctypes import wintypes as wts

# Other imports

wts.BYTE = cts.c_ubyte

# ...
```

Things (*CTypes* related) that would (probably) worth reading:

- Signed / unsigned types: [[SO]: Maximum and minimum value of C types integers from Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485502/4788546)
- Common function calling pitfall: [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546)