# Simplifying Ctype union in Python (to send Keyboard events in Windows)

Tags: python, ctypes

I have the following script that sends a keyboard key every xx seconds (<kbd>F15</kbd> by default), inspired by some code found online

I want to remove the types and union related to Mouse events but cannot make it to work. In particular, I don't know how to remove the class `MOUSEINPUT` and the union of types `_INPUTunion` (removing them will stop sending the keyboard key).

Any suggestion on how to trim the script to a minimum (i.e. only keep code related to Keyboard)?

The following code will send the key "C" to be able to debug.

```
#!/python

import ctypes
import sys
import time

LONG = ctypes.c_long
DWORD = ctypes.c_ulong
ULONG_PTR = ctypes.POINTER(DWORD)
WORD = ctypes.c_ushort

class MOUSEINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ('dx', LONG), ('dy', LONG), ('mouseData', DWORD),
        ('dwFlags', DWORD), ('time', DWORD),
        ('dwExtraInfo', ULONG_PTR)
    )

class KEYBDINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ('wVk', WORD), ('wScan', WORD),
        ('dwFlags', DWORD), ('time', DWORD),
        ('dwExtraInfo', ULONG_PTR)
    )

class _INPUTunion(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = (('mi', MOUSEINPUT), ('ki', KEYBDINPUT))

class INPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('type', DWORD), ('union', _INPUTunion))


def SendInput(*inputs):
    print(inputs[0].union.mi)
    nInputs = len(inputs)
    LPINPUT = INPUT * nInputs
    pInputs = LPINPUT(*inputs)
    cbSize = ctypes.c_int(ctypes.sizeof(INPUT))
    return ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(nInputs, pInputs, cbSize)

INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1

def Input(structure):
    if isinstance(structure, KEYBDINPUT):
        return INPUT(INPUT_KEYBOARD, _INPUTunion(ki=structure))
    else:
        raise TypeError('Cannot create INPUT structure (keyboard)!')

def Keyboard(code, flags=0):
    return Input(KEYBDINPUT(code, code, flags, 0, None))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nb_cycles = 10
    while nb_cycles != 0:
            time.sleep(2)  # 3 seconds
            # Key "c" for debug, but ideally use 0x7E for "F15"
            SendInput(Keyboard(ord("C")))
            sys.stdout.write(".")
            nb_cycles -= 1
```

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you getting? Have you looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx Looks like you just specifying the keyboard structure with the type value set to 1 should work.

Comment: This is a like paradox. When submitting a question, *OP* should reduce it to [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is the very object of the current question :)) . Hint: start by removing the `if isinstance(structure, MOUSEINPUT):` condition, then you can proceed to the mouse related stuff.

Comment: @Tim I tried to remove the class `MOUSEINPUT` but nothing happened when launching. I have updated the question to indicate what I tried. The link is interesting but it does mention an union for `INPUTunion` so I don't know whether the code can be trimmed.

Comment: @CristiFati I have removed some useless parts in my code to make it (slightly) simpler, include the `if isinstance(structure, MOUSEINPUT):` that I previously managed to remove before asking the question. For the rest, it is a big mystery.

Comment: I would try just supplying the KEYBDINPUT structure directly to `SendInput` method. A union is a type construct telling the C compiler to allow either type, there is nothing really special.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"*The Bible*" for tasks like this: [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes). 
I modified your code (found a bunch of problems, out of which some were critical).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys
import time
from ctypes import wintypes as wts


wts.BYTE = cts.c_ubyte


class KEYBDINPUT(cts.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("wVk", wts.WORD),
        ("wScan", wts.WORD),
        ("dwFlags", wts.DWORD),
        ("time", wts.DWORD),
        ("dwExtraInfo", wts.PULONG),
    )


class INPUT(cts.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("type", wts.DWORD),
        ("ki", KEYBDINPUT),
        ("padding", wts.BYTE * 8)
    )


INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1  # Also defined by win32con if you have pywin32 installed

INPUT_LEN = cts.sizeof(INPUT)
LPINPUT = cts.POINTER(INPUT)

user32_dll = cts.windll.user32
SendInput = user32_dll.SendInput
SendInput.argtypes = (wts.UINT, LPINPUT, cts.c_int)
SendInput.restype = wts.UINT


def send_input(_input):
    return SendInput(1, cts.byref(_input), INPUT_LEN)


def keyboard(code, flags=0):
    return INPUT(INPUT_KEYBOARD, (KEYBDINPUT(code, code, flags, 0, None)))


def main(*argv):
    time.sleep(2)
    nb_cycles = 3
    for _ in range(nb_cycles):
        time.sleep(0.5)  # 3 seconds
        # Key "c" for debug, but ideally use 0x7E for "F15"
        ret = send_input(keyboard(ord("C")))
        #print(ret)
        sys.stdout.write(".")
        sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- Initially, I defined the *INPUT* structure having only its 1<sup>st</sup> 2 members, but took a look at [[MS.Learn]: INPUT structure (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-input) and noted that the union consists of:

  - *MOUSEINPUT*
  - *KEYBDINPUT*
  - *HARDWAREINPUT*

  Did some tests and noted that *MOUSEINPUT* has the largest size out of the 3 *struct*s, and it's ***8*** bytes greater than *KEYBDINPUT* (for **both** *032bit* and *064bit*), so I added the (dummy) (*padding*) member. Normally, I wouldn't expect that *SendInput* to go beyond *KEYBDINPUT* size when receiving an *INPUT* structure with *type* set to *INPUT_KEYBOARD*, but the *INPUT* size is required by [[MS.Docs]: SendInput function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)'s *cbSize* arg
- `def SendInput(*inputs):` - in *Python*, *Asterisk* (*******) before an argument does something totally different than in *C*. Check [[SO]: Expanding tuples into arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1993727/4788546) (I didn't find the official *.doc*). I modified the function so that it only sends **one** such structure
- **Check** [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common pitfall when working with *CTypes* (calling functions)
- Use *ctypes.wintypes* for *Win* specific types, don't reinvent the wheel. Not to mention that sometimes mismatches might occur (most recent one that I saw, was *ctypes.c_bool* *vs.* *wintypes.BOOL*)

  - *wts.BYTE* redefinition (not necessary in this case) - a *CTypes* bug: [[SO]: Why ctypes.wintypes.BYTE is signed, but native windows BYTE is unsigned? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75345283/4788546)
- I renamed your functions to be [[Python]: PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) compliant. I also removed some of them, that were no longer needed
- Other small changes that don't worth being mentioned individually

As for testing, I used a *Notepad* window (or any other, "sensitive" to user input):

- Launch the script
- <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd> to the test window (I added the 1<sup>st</sup> instruction (*time.sleep(2)*) from *main* just to give user time to switch windows), and notice the ***c***s "magically" appearing

... Or just launch the script from console, press (and hold) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, then notice the *KeyboardInterrupt* (<kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>) occurrence.

Comment: Awesome explanations. The non-PEP8 functions were from the code I found on the SO and I didn't take the time to rename them. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! Nice being helpful!. *PEP8* rules  are not mandatory but definitely a guideline to follow...

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: @CristiFati `wintypes.PULONG` is not found with Python2 but `wintypes.ULONG` seems to work. Can I replace?

Comment: No, use `ctypes.c_ulonglong`.

Comment: Or better: `ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.ULONG)`.